# What event should be used to handle "clicking" a button in a WPF application on a touchscreen computer?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, wpf-controls, touch-event

I am developing a solution that will be used solely on touch computers. Should I use Click, TouchDown, PreviewTouchDown to listen to the event of clicking the button on the touchscreen using touch? Originally I was using Click but I noticed in some cases that the event didnt fire on first finger tap on the touch screen and had to touch it again to fire. I am using .NET 4.8. Thanks!

Comment: Typically you don't fire until Touch *Up* happens inside the element for any given type of 'button' interaction, regardless of programming language. This way accidental clicks don't submit forms, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you handle the `TouchDown` and also set the `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled` attached property of the `Button` to `false`, the event should be raised as soon as the finger touches the screen:

```
<Button Content="Touch" TouchDown="Button_TouchDown" Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False" />
```

By default and as stated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.touchdown?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077), the event doesn't occur until a finger touches the screen *and moves*.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity what's the difference between TouchDow and PreviewTouchDown, the verbiage is exactly the same in the docs. When is PreviewTouchDown ever used? Thanks again

Comment: The Preview* events are tunneling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8